# Removing custom toolbar view on change of fragment and activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-custom-view, android-toolbar

I've `Activity` A and B. A contains `fragments` which can be navigated by clicking items on navigation drawer. `Activity` B has a custom `toolbar` view. Navigation drawer is available on activity B also as activity B extends activity A. When i return to any `fragment` of `activity` A from B by clicking item on item on drawer, custom view persists. I don't want custom view to be shown on `fragments` of activity A. How can i do that?

Code for main activity goes:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected static int position;
private static boolean isLaunch = true;
protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
protected ListView mDrawerList;
protected Toolbar mToolbar,mToolbar2;
protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
protected View mCustomView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
private SharedPreferences runPrefs;
Menu menu;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(i, -1)));
    }
    //  Garbage collection
    navMenuIcons.recycle();
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    NavDrawerListAdapter adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    if (isLaunch) {
        isLaunch = false;
        displayView(0);
    }
  }


private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    MainActivity.position = position;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentMain();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentLogin();

            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentEmergency();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new FragmentFavourite();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
}
```

Code for another activity (with custom toolbar view)

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_business_result_list, frameLayout);
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    this.businessList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvBusinesslist); // Initialize View Containing Fields of ListView
    this.footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
    this.businessList.addFooterView(footerView);
    this.adapter = new BusinessListDataAdapter(this, this.imgFetcher,
            this.layoutInflator, this.businesses); // initialize BusinessListDataAdapter
    this.businesses = null;
    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    // gets the arguments from previously created intent
    this.metroTxt = myIntent.getStringExtra("key");
    this.metroLoc = myIntent.getStringExtra("loc");
    this.metroId = myIntent.getStringExtra("qt");

    showCustomView(metroTxt, metroLoc, metroId);
    getBusinesses(metroTxt, metroLoc, metroId); // Get Businesses List from server
}

void showCustomView(String metroTxt, String metroLoc, String metroId) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    if (mCustomView == null)
        mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
    mToolbar.removeView(mCustomView);
    mToolbar.addView(mCustomView);
}
```

Comment: Hiding actionbar in Activity A

Comment: not actually hiding action bar, only custom toolbar view ( it contains custom input field). I need to display this on activity B only.

Comment: yes toolbar also actionbar, right? `getSupportActionBar().hide()`

Comment: yes it's working as actionbar

Comment: I don't want the whole action bar to be hidden, only custom view should not be shown.. getSupportActionBar().hide() hides whole action bar and its item plus it is not working when fragment is called form activity B

Comment: what `mToolbar.removeView(mCustomView);` means? so you can remove and add

Comment: it is to check if custom view exists and if remove that and add this

Comment: But it is not working on fragments as fragments are associated with activity A and custom toolbar is associated with activity B